# Argument of ? has an extra }

Tags: latex, hyperref

i try  to make fillable forms for my students. Beofre i updated my code mostly worked.
I tried to update all packages and now, if i use \usepackage{hyperref} i get the following error.

! Argument of � has an extra }.

\par
l.132 \end{document}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything. For example,` \def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce this error. If you simply proceed now, the` \par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type` 2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before � was complete.

\par
l.132 \end{document}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Approximatly 100 Times.

If i comment it out there is no problem at all (except for the fact, that i cant use Textfields...)

Someone an idea what i could change so i get my forms back?

I already tried using \usepackage{hyperref} as the last package and deleted aux and toc files.
I reinstalled the package like 15 times but nothing works.

Comment: Are you using the `utf8x` option for inputenc?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! I got the same error message as the OP and replacing `utf8x` by `utf8` solved the problem (cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc)).

Comment: @Karlo You're welcome! Instead of replacing the option, you could also just remove `\usepackage{inputenc}` because `utf8` is the default since a couple of years.